# How to filter values to be within range in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried

```py
df = df.loc[20000 <= df['column'] <= 100_000]
```

but got the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I thought pandas supported such notation?

What am I meant to do instead?

Comment: `df.loc[df['column'].between(1,10)]`, you can't chain series as native python like that

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = df.loc[(20000 <= df['column']) & (df['column'] <= 100_000)]
```

Comment: [Why be verbose when you don't need to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76131493/how-to-filter-values-to-be-within-range-in-pandas#comment134261892_76131493)?

Comment: @BigBen I think it makes it clearer how to chain conditions in a more general situation, since the author asked also about pandas support for "such notation".